# jekyll homepage title is empty

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Currently [aaronirwin.com](https://aaronirwin.com) has an empty title tag like `<title></title>`

I defined `title` in the [index front matter](https://github.com/ryanve/aaronirwin.com/blob/master/index.html) and am using `page.title` in the [template](https://github.com/ryanve/aaronirwin.com/blob/master/_layouts/default.html)

[Code is in github pages](https://github.com/ryanve/aaronirwin.com)

How do I get the title to render?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the site title in the index

```
<title>{% if page.title %}{{ page.title }}{% else %}{{ site.title }}{% endif %}</title>
```

and define the site title in the _config.yml file.

Comment: Thanks do you know why the index front matter doesn't work as `page.title`?

Comment: Does front matter work at all in the index?

Comment: I dont know, but it makes sense to use the front matters of the site in the index

Comment: I like having the title in the same file as the content

Comment: Defining `title` in the config `defaults` works as `page.title` https://github.com/ryanve/aaronirwin.com/pull/111/files